# Page not re-rendering after button click

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a react class component which produces a product showcase using react-masonry. I now want to add filtering functionality with filter options displayed as buttons and on each click, the page elements should be filtered and the masonry display rerendered.
The filter functions work fine but I was not able to get the masonry to rerender.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-component'
import Product from 'components/Product'


const masonryOptions = {
    transitionDuration: 0
};

class Gallery extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            filter:props.filter,
            elements:props.elements,
            type:props.type,
        }
         this.handleFilterClick=this.handleFilterClick.bind(this)
    }


    handleFilterClick(filter){
        console.log(filter)

        this.setState({filter:filter})
        console.log(this.state.filter)
    }

    filterProducts (elements,filter){
        const filteredArray=elements.filter(function(el){
            for (let i in el.tags) { 
                if (el.tags[i].slug===filter){

                    return true;

                }

            } 
            return false
        })
        return filteredArray;
    }

    renderGallery(){
        const type=this.state.type
        const elements=this.state.elements
        var filter=this.state.filter
        const filteredElements = elements
        if (filter !=="*"){
            const filteredElements = this.filterProducts(elements,filter)
        }

        const childElements = filteredElements.map(function(element,key){

           if (element.mainPhoto!=null && element.isDogFood==type){
           return (

               <Product key={key} element={element}/>

            );} else{
                return null;
            }
        });
         return (



                <Masonry
                    className={'my-gallery-class'} // default ''
                    options={masonryOptions} // default {}
                    disableImagesLoaded={false} // default false
                    updateOnEachImageLoad={false} // default false and works only if disableImagesLoaded is false

                >
                 <div className="col-md-12">

                    <ul className="filter text-center text-inline">
                      <li>
                        <button data-filter="*" className="selected">Tüm Ürünler</button>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <button filter="nograin">Tahılsız</button>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <button filter="seafood">Deniz Mahsülleri</button>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <button filter="poultry">Beyaz Et</button>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <button filter="redmeat">Kırmızı Et</button>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <button filter="pate" onClick={() =>{this.handleFilterClick("pate")}}>Püre</button>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                    {childElements}
                </Masonry>


        );

    }

    render() {
       return (
       this.renderGallery()
       )
    }

}

Gallery.propTypes={

    type: PropTypes.bool
}
export default Gallery
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead of using props in `constructor`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-component'
import Product from 'components/Product'


const masonryOptions = {
    transitionDuration: 0
};

class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // Don't assign direct value in constructor as constructor function 
      // calls only at initialization
      filter:props.filter,
      elements:props.elements,
      type:props.type,
    }
    this.handleFilterClick=this.handleFilterClick.bind(this)
  }

  getDerivedStateFromProps (props, prevState) {
    if(//Put a valid condition) {
      return {
        filter: props.filter,
        elements: props.elements,
        type: props.type
      }
    }
    return {}
  }

  handleFilterClick(filter){
    console.log(filter)
    this.setState({filter:filter})
    console.log(this.state.filter)
  }

  filterProducts (elements,filter){
    const filteredArray=elements.filter(function(el){
      for (let i in el.tags) { 
          if (el.tags[i].slug===filter){
            return true;
          }
      } 
      return false
    })
    return filteredArray;
  }

  renderGallery(){
    const type=this.state.type
    const elements=this.state.elements
    var filter=this.state.filter
    const filteredElements = elements
    if (filter !=="*"){
        const filteredElements = this.filterProducts(elements,filter)
    }

    const childElements = filteredElements.map(function(element,key){

     if (element.mainPhoto!=null && element.isDogFood==type){
     return (
         <Product key={key} element={element}/>
      );} else {
        return null;
      }
    });
    return (
      <Masonry
        className={'my-gallery-class'} // default ''
        options={masonryOptions} // default {}
        disableImagesLoaded={false} // default false
        updateOnEachImageLoad={false} // default false and works only if disableImagesLoaded is false
      >
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <ul className="filter text-center text-inline">
            <li>
              <button data-filter="*" className="selected">Tüm Ürünler</button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button filter="nograin">Tahılsız</button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button filter="seafood">Deniz Mahsülleri</button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button filter="poultry">Beyaz Et</button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button filter="redmeat">Kırmızı Et</button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button filter="pate" onClick={() =>{this.handleFilterClick("pate")}}>Püre</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        {childElements}
      </Masonry>
    );
  }

  render() {
   return (
     this.renderGallery()
   )
  }
}

Gallery.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.bool
}

export default Gallery
```